# Catching a close window call from tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I'd like to reload certain elements in my page via ajax whenever a tinymce window gets closed but I can't find any references to any event calls that I can use. [This page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.WindowManager.close) mentions an onClose event but I can't find its page in tinymce api.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no onClose event, but you my user the [onRemove](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onRemove) event. Here is the configuration init code for this

```
// Adds an observer to the onRemove event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onRemove.add(function(ed) {
          console.debug('Editor was removed: ' + ed.id);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried using this but it doesn't seem to work. The event doesn't seem to get called. There aren't any js errors showing up so I'm assuming that means the code is correct.

Comment: Clicking on the close button.

Comment: onRemove will work in combination with the command: tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, editor_id);

Comment: it looks like. can you tell me what code is used to embed the close button in the button config (the close button is a button of the tinymce toolbar?)? this way i might be able to find another solution

Comment: I've actually been trying to find that out myself without much luck. it's not high on my priority list so I haven't devoted much time to it. in any case, this is for the close button of the image plugin. I've at least determined that the button isn't in the plugin's html page.

Comment: can you use firebug and inspect that button - please post the info you get here